# Unterminated string at Jayrock.Json.TextParser.NextString(Char quote)

Tags: json, genexus

On Windows Event Viewer, I see every 10 or 15 minutes the following warning:

> Unterminated string. at Jayrock.Json.TextParser.NextString(Char quote)
>   at Jayrock.Json.JsonTextReader.Parse() at
>   Jayrock.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseObjectMemberValue() at
>   Jayrock.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadToken() at
>   Jayrock.Json.JsonReader.DeserializeNext(IParserOutput output) at
>   Jayrock.Json.JsonReader.DeserializeNext(IParserOutput output) at
>   Jayrock.Json.JsonReader.DeserializeNext(IParserOutput output) at
>   GeneXus.Http.HttpAjaxContext.GetGXStateTokens(String state) at
>   GeneXus.Http.HttpAjaxContext.LoadFormVars(HttpContext
>   localHttpContext) at GeneXus.Http.GXHttpHandler.InitPrivates() at
>   GeneXus.Http.GXHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
>   completedSynchronously)
>   https://xxxxxx.yyyyyy.com:443/vd/webpanel.aspx?4ace10dc56b739f064f3898c27e0bb52,gx-no-cache=1523577046011

On Web Browser there is no error loading the panel so I cant see which line of  code is causing this.

How can I debug my code? (I use Genexus X Ev3 U11 C# Generator)

Answer (score 0):

verify your code if exist

&var.fromjson(&var2)

comment, and try again.